# Android SimpleDateFormat not recognizing daylight time

Tags: android, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a string of time given in GMT to a new string with the user's timezone. SimpleDateFormat is parsing the time as PST while it should be PDT. Printing the current time provides the correct timezone. I have a feeling the problem might be with using a date, but I am unsure what to do.

Sample code:

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Log.e("Current time", sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        sdf.applyPattern("HHmm z");
        Date date = sdf.parse("2137 GMT");
        sdf.applyPattern("hh:mm a z");
        Log.e("Parsed time", sdf.format(date));
    }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

The two logs produce:

```
E/Current time﹕ 02:37 PM PDT
E/Parsed time﹕ 01:37 PM PST
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to figure out the issue. By default a date object is set for Jan 1, 1970. Daylight savings time does not apply during January so it wasn't using it. What I did was add the day of the year to the pattern and then get the current date from the calendar.

Updated portion:

```
sdf.applyPattern("D HHmm z");
Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+" 0420 GMT");
```

This correctly adjust for daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

The date that's in used is during daylight savings time

Comment: Thank you for the response. I might not have been clear, but I want the Parsed time to be in daylight time. It is currently displaying as standard time.